# changing settings to c# in visual studio 2010 express edition

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How do I change from the default settings (which I suppose supports VB) in visual studio 2010 express to support C# code
?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2010 edition comes in several versions.

C#
C++
Basic
Web Developer

Download the C# version

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express